# Get a random permutation of a word that is different from the word

Tags: python, random, permutation, shuffle

I would like to get a **random** permutation of the letters of a word, **if possible**, else the word itself.

How can this be done efficiently?

This is what I have for now

```
from itertools import permutations
import random

word = 'some_word'
permutations = [''.join(permutation) for permutation in permutations(word)]
random.shuffle(permutations)
scrambled_word = word
for permutation in permutations:
    if permutation != word:
        scrambled_word = permutation
        break
```

Basically, I am just getting the first permutation of all the permutations of the word. I will be doing this operation for many word and I find this method inefficient. In general, it should be unnecessary to get all the permutations of a given word.

I had in mind that I could somehow have an iterable of random permutations from which I can just retrieve the first permutation. How can this be done in Python? The function `permutations` of `itertools` is an iterable, but the elements are not in a random order. I need a **random** permutation, so that it will not look like the original word.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by the docs for `random.shuffle`, you can use [`random.sample`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html?highlight=sample#random.sample):

```
scrambled_word = ''.join(random.sample(word, k=len(word)))
```

That won't prevent you from getting back the original word occasionally, since that's a valid permutation. If you don't allow the original, you're not getting a truly random sample. You can filter the original out if you want to; just try again if you don't like the word you got (making sure that you detect the case where all the letters are the same):

```
def scramble(word):
  while True:
    scrambled_word = ''.join(random.sample(word, k=len(word)))
    if scrambled_word != word or all(c == word[0] for c in word):
      return scrambled_word
```

Comment: Does it guarantee that the result is different from the original word (if possible)?

Comment: @Gradient: no, it generates a random permutation and the original is a valid permutation.

Comment: @gradient: added some code to check for the identity shuffle

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to @rici's answer. This code will check if the word is composed of only one letter.

CODE:

```
word = "aaa"

while True:
    scrambled_word = ''.join(random.sample(word, k=len(word)))
    if word.count(word[0]) == len(word) or scrambled_word != word:
        break
print(scrambled_word)
```